# HMTL5 Video in background Desktop & Img in BG on Mobile

Tags: html, video, mobile

I currently have an HTML5 video looping in the background at a fixed position.  However, when the site is viewed on mobile I want it to go away. Is there a way to do this in the CSS? Possibly a media query for certain screen sizes?

How do I put the HTML5 video code into the HTML without it being active on the mobile site as well as the intended desktop version?

This is the code I am using:

```
<body>
<video autoplay loop muted poster="img/BGvideo.jpg" class="video-bg">
<source src="video/medium.webm" type="video/webm">
<source src="video/medium.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use javascript to do this work:

```
var size = window.innerWidth;   
 if(size == 320){
   document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].removeAttribute('autoplay');
 }
```